# How to create a thread whose main function requires a reference argument?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, reference

I need to create a reference to a variable in a thread. When I do it like in the code below, I get two errors:

> C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
>
> C2893: Failed to specialize function template '`unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)`'

How to code it correctly?

```
#include <thread>

void foo(double a, double& b)
{
  b = a;
}

int main()
{
  double a = 0.0, b = 0.0;

  std::thread f(foo, a, b);

  f.join();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Thread function pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424653/c-thread-function-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is what [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) and its two creator functions, `std::ref` and `std::cref` are for:

```
std::thread f(foo, a, std::ref(b));
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08b31a65bc03b099)

`std::reference_wrapper<T>` is an object which effectively behaves like a rebindable reference: it defines `operator T&` for implicit conversin into `T&`, but can be reassigned. It is intended precisely for situations where a "copyable reference" is needed, such as `std::bind` or `std::thread`.

Use `std::ref` to create a non-const reference to `x`, and `std::cref` to create a const reference to `x`.

Comment: `std::ref` works perfectly for any kind of pointer. Sorry for my previous comment, I found a mistake in my code.